# Generate xml and save it when calling a generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ajax, handler

Im using the following code to save an xml file

```
  HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    string xmlString = "<xml>blah</xml>";
    string fileName = "ExportedForm.xml";

    response.StatusCode = 200;

    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _Buffer.Length.ToString());

    response.ContentType = "application-download";
    response.Write(xmlString);
```

This works fine when binding to a button onlick event for example. But im generating my xml in a generic handler.ashx. So i want to wait until the ajax call is complete before i do the stuff above. Can i do it all in the handler? The ajax call is made by jquery and the xml data is based on input fields on my page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class GenerateXML : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        var resp = context.Response;

        resp.ContentType = "text/xml";
        resp.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        resp.Write( "<xml>i am xml</xml>" );
    }
}
```

Then mod the web.config of your project.

```
<httpHandlers>
    <!--...other things..-->
    <add verb="*" path="xml.generate" type="YOUR_NAMESPACE.GenerateXML, YOUR_DLL" />
</httpHandlers>
```